# ubuntu14.04 packages on bionic universe (18.04)

Tags: 14.04, apt, 18.04, package-management, software-installation

I am trying to install [YOURLS](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-yourls-your-own-url-shortener-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux/) which needs `php7.2-fpm`. However, when installing it, I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.                                 
 php7.2-fpm : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 7.2.12-1+ub
untu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed                                   
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is a machine I did update from 14.04 a while back. I appear to have a bunch of packages installed still from 14.04:

```
; apt list --installed | ag ubuntu14 | wc -l                                    

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts. 

49
```

***How do I fix this?***

Here additional information from commenter's request:

```
; apt-cache policy php7.2-common                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
php7.2-common:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  Installed: 7.2.12-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Candidate: 7.2.12-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Version table:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 *** 7.2.12-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     7.2.3-1ubuntu1 500                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

and

```
; grep -R trusty /etc/apt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
grep: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt.postgresql.org.gpg: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-fast-stable-precise.list.save:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-fast-stable-precise.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                            
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ultrafredde-ppa-precise.list.save:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ultrafredde/ppa/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ultrafredde-ppa-precise.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ultrafredde/ppa/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                            
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-unstable-trusty.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                          
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gophers-archive-trusty.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                             
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-fast-stable-precise.list:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                     
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-fast-stable-precise.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-precise.list.distUpgrade:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                               
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-precise.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                           
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pi-rho-dev-precise.list.distUpgrade:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                   
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pi-rho-dev-precise.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                               
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-unstable-trusty.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                              
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fish-shell-release-2-trusty.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                   
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/certbot-certbot-trusty.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                      
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fish-shell-release-2-trusty.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                            
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ultrafredde-ppa-precise.list:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ultrafredde/ppa/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                     
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ultrafredde-ppa-precise.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ultrafredde/ppa/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/certbot-certbot-trusty.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                             
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ultrafredde-ppa-precise.list.distUpgrade:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ultrafredde/ppa/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                         
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ultrafredde-ppa-precise.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ultrafredde/ppa/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                     
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-fast-stable-precise.list.distUpgrade:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                         
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-fast-stable-precise.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                     
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php-trusty.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                                            
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php-trusty.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                                       
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pi-rho-dev-precise.list:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                               
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pi-rho-dev-precise.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                           
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fish-shell-release-2-trusty.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                        
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/certbot-certbot-trusty.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-precise.list:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                           
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-precise.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                       
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php-trusty.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                                
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ppa-trusty.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                            
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-unstable-trusty.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                     
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ppa-trusty.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                                   
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pi-rho-dev-precise.list.save:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                          
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pi-rho-dev-precise.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                      
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gophers-archive-trusty.list.distUpgrade:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                      
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-precise.list.save:1:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                      
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-precise.list.save:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty                                                                                                                                                                  
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ppa-trusty.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                                        
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gophers-archive-trusty.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu trusty main                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:13:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:14:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:18:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:19:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:24:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:25:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:26:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:27:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:34:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:35:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:36:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:37:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:44:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse                                                                                                                                                                                                   
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:45:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse                                                                                                                                                                                               
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:47:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:48:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:49:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:50:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:51:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:52:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
```

However:

```
; apt update                                                                    
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]     
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                      
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]  
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (253 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done                                                   
Building dependency tree                                                        
Reading state information... Done                                               
All packages are up-to-date.
```

Comment: That is one of the drawbacks of doing and upgrade some stuff get's left behind. You might try running the following command and see if it clears the problem 
sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: @kc1di Tried it, it did nothing but did return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key clue here is in the apt-cache output:

```
 *** 7.2.12-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

1) This means that the package is NOT provided by any enabled sources, yet it's in your local /var/cache/apt/archives.

2) Looking at the way the package is named, looks like the package is from some non-Ubuntu source.

The most likely way it got into your local cache is that you had a non-Ubuntu source enabled sometime in the past. When you disabled the non-Ubuntu source, seems like you perhaps forgot to uninstall the packages from that source.

Happily, it's usually quite easy to fix: [Uninstall all the non-Ubuntu packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) and return to stock Ubuntu. Then apt will work properly again.